# Flex: DataGrid with dynamic columns with data from multiple DB tables

Tags: apache-flex, datagrid, blazeds

**Introduction:** I'm using java, oracle, flex, blazeDS etc. The part of the DB that is relevant to the task i am trying to accomplish is illustrated in the image below:
[image: Task, User and the M:N relationship Task_User]

The *Task* table will also have a field called *enabled* , which i forgot in the figure below :) This field is used to enable some of the tasks based on various criteria, when an admin user presses a "Generate task list" button in the GUI.

Based on this generation of the task list, the users in the system should see a grid as the one displayed in the figure below :
[image: Task list]

This task list should display all the enabled task as illustrated above. The first three columns are retrived from the *Task* table in the DB, while the next columns(Column_4....Column_N) are generated based on the number of users in the *User* table. These columns should display the users alias. Each user is part of a UserGroup(Group), which i will model in either a separate table or in the *User* table itself, as illustrated in figure 1. The Numbers in the grid are based on the Time field in the *Task_User* table, while the first row below the users shows the sum of the times for each user.

**Question:** Im still learning Flex, and looking for every help i can get on accomplishing my goal :) I figure i have to implement a datagrid with dynamic columns. But how will the dataprovider work in this scenario? For each enabled taskid the grid has to fill the right user columns with time values. Any tips/help would be much appreciated! It is also important that loading this grid doesnt take to long :)

Is it possible to get horizontal and vertical text in the grid(like shown above)?

Comment: I will post how i solved this problem sometime during the comming days, in case somebody meets a similar dilemma :)